# One-To-Many find all ids not containing specific values in JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, persistence, eclipselink, criteria, criteria-api

I'm building a method that constructs Predicates for a CriteriaQuery based on some filter values on a webpage. My problems started when I tried to add handling of the Eco-label filter. The idea is that an Item is not eco-labeled if it's itemProperties values is not one of the values returned from `ecoLabelHelper.getEcoProperties(filterCriteria.getCustomer())`. I want to get all the CustomerItems, that does not have any of the values returned from `getEcoProperties()` I tried two different approaches to determine when an Item is not Eco-Labeled, labeled as Attempt 1 and 2 in the code.
Attempt 1 fails due to *"t11.ITEMPROPERTIES Multi-part identifier could not be bound"* and attempt 2 is so slow that I've never seen it finish. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm new to the CriteriaBuilder and CriteriaQuery APIs, and I find them pretty confusing to use honestly.

Eclipselink 2.6.2.

The elementCollection "mp_item_properties" hold one-many values per ID.

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mp_item", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "itemno, supplier_id"), @Index(columnList = "itemGroupIdSupplier, itemGroupSupplier"),
        @Index(columnList = "itemgroup_id") }, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "itemno, supplier_id" }))
public class Item extends BaseShopEntity {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "mp_item_properties", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mp_item_id"))
    @BatchFetch(value = BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    private Set<String> itemProperties;

...
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mp_customer_item", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "item_id, customer_id", unique = true) })
public class CustomerItem extends BaseShopEntity {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private Item item;
```

The method that builds the predicates for the where-statement:

```
public CriteriaQuery<CustomerItem> buildQuery() {
        CriteriaQuery<CustomerItem> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CustomerItem.class);
        root = criteriaQuery.from(CustomerItem.class);
        Join<CustomerItem, Item> itemJoin = (Join<CustomerItem, Item>) (Object) root.fetch(ITEM);

        conditions = new ArrayList<>();
        conditions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<Customer>get(CUSTOMER), filterCriteria.getCustomer()));
        conditions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemJoin.<Boolean>get(HIDDEN), false));

        // Omitted code, adds conditions based on filter values

        if (filterCriteria.getEcoLabelFilter() != null) {
            Predicate customerItemIsEco = criteriaBuilder.equal(customerMappingJoin.<Boolean>get(ECO), true);
            if (filterCriteria.getEcoLabelFilter()) {               
                Predicate itemIsEco = itemJoin.<String>get(ITEM_PROPERTIES).in(ecoLabelHelper.getEcoProperties(filterCriteria.getCustomer()));
                conditions.add(criteriaBuilder.or(itemIsEco, customerItemIsEco));
            }
            else {
                // Attempt 1
                Join<CustomerItem, Item> itemJoinCustom = (Join<CustomerItem, Item>) (Object) root.fetch(ITEM, JoinType.LEFT);
                itemJoinCustom.on(itemJoinCustom.<String>get(ITEM_PROPERTIES).in(ecoLabelHelper.getEcoProperties(filterCriteria.getCustomer())));
                conditions.add(itemJoinCustom.<String>get(ITEM_PROPERTIES).isNull());       
                
                // Attempt 2
                Subquery<Integer> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Integer.class);
                Root<CustomerItem> itemProperties = subquery.from(CustomerItem.class);
                Join<CustomerItem, Item> itemPropertiesJoin = (Join<CustomerItem, Item>) (Object) itemProperties.fetch(ITEM);
                subquery.select(itemProperties.<Integer>get(ID));
                subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<Customer>get(CUSTOMER), filterCriteria.getCustomer()), itemPropertiesJoin.get(ITEM_PROPERTIES).in(ecoLabelHelper.getEcoProperties(filterCriteria.getCustomer()))));
                subquery.distinct(true);
                Predicate itemIsNotEco = criteriaBuilder.in(itemProperties.get(ID)).value(subquery).not();
                conditions.add(itemIsNotEco);
            }
        }
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(asList(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(ID))));
        return criteriaQuery;
    }
```

The conditions-list is then used in:

```
if (criteriaQuery != null) {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = criteriaQueryHelper.getBuilder();
            Predicate conditions = builder.and(criteriaQueryHelper.getConditions().toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            criteriaQuery.select(criteriaQueryHelper.getRoot());
            criteriaQuery.where(conditions);
            resultList = new LimitedList<>(em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(MAX_RESULT).getResultList());
            CriteriaQuery<Long> countQ = getCountQuery(builder, conditions, criteriaQueryHelper.getRoot());
            resultList.setRealSize(em.createQuery(countQ).getSingleResult().intValue());
}
```

Thankful for any advice, cheers.

Comment: First, turn on EclipseLink's SQL logging to see what it issues for your attempts ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging ).  Second, you are using root.fetch - did you mean to use root.join ?  Fetch causes the relationship to be fetched with the root, but it cannot be used for filtering as you are attempting to do. You can try writing out the query you want in SQL or JPQL and then converting to criteria query formats - sometimes its a bit easier to understand and follow.

Comment: @Chris I did turn on logging, so I can see the generated SQL in the console, however I still need to manually insert the parameters (which takes a lot of time for big queries). Maybe there is some setting generating the SQL with the parameters already inserted in the query? 
Regarding using fetch, why can't it be used for filtering? I used it for getting access to itemProperties in Item. I did start by coming up with solutions in native SQL, and then translated to Criteria, but I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Chris, I tried using root.join(ITEM, JoinType.LEFT) instead, but I still run into the problem "t11.ITEMPROPERTIES Multi-part identifier could not be bound". With a normal inner join the error does not appear. I need a left join in order to fetch all the values that does not satisfy the join-condition.